# Calling an async method from an emit event

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have a process working within my application which emits events using `BaseEventEmitter` from pyee. As I'm subscribing to these events, I'd like to forward them and call a web service, but as the web service call is async, I can't find a way to call it using await...

Setting up subscription to the event:

```
my_process.log.on('debug', lambda m : trace_debug(m))
```

The async `trace_debug` function looks like this:

```
async def trace_debug(message):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application-json'}
        async with session.post('http://myapiapi', json = {"message":message}, headers = headers) as response:
            return await response.text()
```

I've tried await in lamda...

```
my_process.log.on('debug', lambda m : await trace_debug(m))
```

...which result in `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function`

I've tried calling it with asyncio:

```
my_process.log.on('debug', lambda m : await asyncio.run(trace_debug(m))
```

...but then I run into a runtime error saying `asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

Is this considered bad praxis? Is there a better way?

Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `my_process.log.on` expects a sync method in his second argument, if you want to run an async method in a sync way, you can use this

`my_process.log.on('debug', lambda m : asyncio.get_running_loop().run_until_complete(trace_debug(m)))`

Keep in mind that this blocks the event loop until the method is complete.
If you want to run the method in the background you can use this

`my_process.log.on('debug', lambda m : asyncio.create_task(trace_debug(m)))`
Which will schedule the task and run it asynchronously when the event loop is free

Edit:
Although I think it might be better to either use a sync method or find an events library that can work with async methods

Comment: Thank you Ron. Blocking the event loop or the thread while calling the web service is my concern. Using the `asyncio.create_task` almost worked but never got pass the second await (`async with aiohttp.ClientSession()`). My background in JS and I'm quite new to Python so please excuse me

Comment: @wmmhihaa With the way that the async event loop works, the task will only run when the event loop is released, so I assume you never release it in your code. Can you try to run `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in the next line after the `my_process.log.on`? The event loop works best if you `await` a lot of times, otherwise, you might be better using threads?